# Using <Link> to designate a default folder

Tags: html

Okay so here's the question: in HTML is it possible to, using the `link` tag in the `head`, set a default folder location? For example, say I break up my files on my server by page and have one called baseball and in the baseball folder I've got one called images. Baseball is a page in this example, and all the images I'm using for that page are coming form `\baseball\images`
so in this example I want to do this

```
link href = "\baseball\images\"
```

so later on when I need to pull an image from that folder all I have to type is:

```
img src = "Pitcher.jpg"
```

*instead of*

```
img src = "\baseball\images\Pitcher.jpg"
```

Is there a way to do that, maybe not with `link`, but let's say `a` is done in the `head` part of the document?

Comment: use base tag eg: `<base href="\baseball\images**" target="_blank">`

Answer (score 1):

Use `<base>` tag

eg: `<base href="\baseball\images**" target="_blank">`

> The HTML  element specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document.There is maximum one `<base>` element in a document.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base